# Regex.Replace generates a space in the LinqPad output window out of nowhere

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm writing a script to assist me in converting a set of text files to markdown. One of the things this script does is applying italics and title formatting to figure titles, which are lines that start with some spaces and the word "Figure". This is my code:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "^ +(Figure.*)$", "##### _$1_", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

If I use this to convert this text:

```
A Foobar is cool stuff, as we can see in Figure 1.1:

  Figure 1.1  This is a Foobar

More text here.
```

...then I get this:

```
A Foobar is cool stuff, as we can see in Figure 1.1:

##### _Figure 1.1  This is a Foobar _

More text here.
```

...which is what I want except for one small detail: there's a space added right before the last underscore character in the LinqPad output window. I don't know where this comes from, as it's not present in the original text (there's a CRLF sequence right after "Foobar"). What's wrong with my regular expression or with how I use it?

**EDIT:** Full executable program demonstrating the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text =
@"A Foobar is cool stuff, as we can see in Figure 1.1:

  Figure 1.1  This is a Foobar

More text here.";

        text = Regex.Replace(text, "^ +(Figure.*)$", "##### _$1_", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: The [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e+%2b%28Figure.*%29%24&i=A+Foobar+is+cool+stuff%2c+as+we+can+see+in+Figure+1.1%3a%0d%0a%0d%0a++Figure+1.1++This+is+a+Foobar%0d%0a&r=%23%23%23%23%23+_%241_&o=m) shows no extra space is added. Please share a reproducible example.

Comment: If there is some other code involved, you probably want to make sure CR stays out of the captured text, then try `"^ +(Figure.*?)\r?$"` or `"^ +(Figure[^\r\n]*)"`

Comment: And here's a minimal C# program that *doesn't* demonstrate the problem: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/8879cf9aee5177baad8d235341027331 A similar program that *does* demonstrate the problem would help a lot.

Comment: Sorry, the example was not clear because it didn't show that there's indeed a CRLF after the figure title, I have updated it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Both of your suggestions work fine. If you want to convert them to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I see, but your code in question still does not do what you say. If you could share a snippet showing how you managed to add a space there, it would be more helpful than my posting a guess solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Done!

Comment: Yeah, but as I assumed before, there is a line break, not a space, "inserted", see https://ideone.com/Oi5HSL

Comment: Damn. LinqPad's output window tricked me, it converts that line break into a space. I should just have generated to exe and run it in the console.

Comment: Now, it is clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` pattern in a .NET regex matches a CR symbol. It is at the end of the text captured into Group 1, thus you have a line break before the last `_` in your replacement. As per your feedback, LinqPad's output window replaces the CR symbol with a "space".

Replace `.` with `[^\r\n]` that will match any char but CR and LF chars, and remove `$` as there is no longer need to assert the end of the line (the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option is still necessary so as `^` could match the start of the line):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "A Foobar is cool stuff, as we can see in Figure 1.1:\r\n\r\n  Figure 1.1  This is a Foobar\r\n\r\nMore text here.";
        text = Regex.Replace(text, "^ +(Figure[^\r\n]*)", "##### _$1_", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/PIVGcU).